# Python with statement rename as none(context manager)

Tags: with-statement, contextmanager

Is there a way to implement with statement rename as none?
For instance,

```
class MyClass(object):
   def test(self,s):
      print s
```

then I want to execute this string code in the users's context, such as

```
with MyClass(a):
    test("hello")
```

then it will print out "hello"
What would be the design pattern and how do I convert user's code this way?